# Apply Padding to td or th if it :has() input. How?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to apply padding to `td` or `th` elements within a table but only if they contain an `input` element. I'm looking for a CSS-only solution.

Here is the HTML structure I'm working with:

```html
<table id="table4">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="name1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td><input type="number" name="name2"></td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- More rows... -->
</table>
```

And here's what I've tried so far, which isn't working:

```css
#table4 th:has(input),
#table4 td:has(input) {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Is there any way to apply padding to only those `td` or `th` elements that directly contain an `input` with pure CSS?

Or does CSS lack parent selectors, and this cannot be achieved with pure CSS if you need to selectively apply padding to `td` or `th` elements based on their child content?

Or maybe `has` is not well supported?!

Comment: HA. It appears From FireFox version 103: the `:has()` feature is behind the `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` preference (needs to be set to `true`). To change preferences in Firefox, visit `about:config`. Chrome `:has()` native support. Edge `:has()` native support.

Comment: actually you are adding padding: 0 ... try a bigger value

Comment: `:has()` is slated to land in Firefox in December. In the meantime, have you considered using a negative margin on the input element?

Comment: Suchislife, you wanna give padding: 0 to the ```<th> ``` or ```<td>``` that contains ```<input>```?

Comment: In addition, you might as well correct the ```<th>``` part.  I am wondering why you put together ```<th>``` and ```<td>``` in one parent.

Comment: Do you want your CSS to work in FireFox?

Comment: Correct. The condition is: IF `th` or `td` CONTAIN `input`, THEN set `th` or `td` padding to `0`. Basically, I am creating a CSS rule that CHECKS PRESENCE OF CHILD to style THE PARENT.